# How to make Comma delimited data into individual rows in a new table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

the values in a row are being captured like this

```
Item type    Item name 
1,2,3,        abc, def, ghi,
```

My goal is to insert each value in a new table like the following

```
Item type    Item name
1            abc
2            def
3            ghi
```

This is the only way I can capture the info for now so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I am not a developor.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6838353/27535 (updated)

Comment: @gbn that mullet is glorious. I must avert my eyes.

Comment: Do not store comma separated values in a single column. You should seriously consider re-designing the datamodel.

Comment: Since you said that you're not a devolper: Can you use SSMS? do you prefer a excel based answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
      a VARCHAR(200)
    , b VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO @table(a, b)
VALUES 
    ('1,2,3,', 'abc, def, ghi,'),
    ('1,2,3,4,', 'test1, test2, test3, test4,')

SELECT 
      [Item name] = LTRIM(data.p)
    , [Item type] = data.r
FROM (
    SELECT 
          p = p.value('(.)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
        , po = p.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i])', 'int')
        , r = r.value('(.)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
        , ro = r.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i])', 'int')
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              txml = CAST('<r><s>' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(t.a, 1, LEN(t.a) - 1), ',', '</s>' + '<s>') + '</s></r>' AS XML)
            , kxml = CAST('<r><s>' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(t.b, 1, LEN(t.b) - 1), ',', '</s>' + '<s>') + '</s></r>' AS XML)  
        FROM @table t
    ) d
    CROSS APPLY kxml.nodes('/r/s') t(p)
    CROSS APPLY txml.nodes('/r/s') k(r)
) data
WHERE data.po = data.ro
```

**Output:**

```
Item name   Item type
----------- ----------
abc         1
def         2
ghi         3
test1       1
test2       2
test3       3
test4       4
```

Comment: I can't normalize the database because this is getting captured through sharepoint and unfortunately this is the only way i can see multiple values under same column

Comment: So where exactly do I provide the table and column names Devart?

Comment: Please try updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Devart, your solution was very helpful.